# Writing payoff matrix and understanding zero-sum game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory

I have an example in my book that states the following problem:

> i) Write the payoff matrix of the two players for rock-paper-scissors,
>   where the losing player gives $1 to the winning player.
>
> ii) Is it a zero-sum game?

I have the solutions to the problem, but I'm honestly just having a hard time understanding them. Can someone please walk me through these questions?

Comment: Each entry in the matrix has the ordered pair $(a,b)$ where $a$ is what Player A wins/loses, and $b$ is what Player B wins/loses.

Comment: If there is only one number, then it refers to what the "row player" wins/loses. The game is zero-sum because either player's loss is the other's gain.